# Unable to access external hard drive - error mounting /dev/sdc1 at /media/

Tags: mount, hard-drive

I have a 2TB external drive, whose access I had before I accidentally run some check my smart TV requested.

Here's what it prompts when I try to open it: [i.stack.imgur.com/vNdR0.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vNdR0.png)

```
Unable to access "2TB"

Error mounting /dev/sdc1 at /media/angelo/2TB: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/sbc1, missing codepage or helper program, or other error
```

To be precise: I can't access it from Ubuntu 22.04. I can normally access it from Windows 10 and from my smart TV.

Edit: This is what Windows return when I run `chkdsk`:

```
F:\>chkdsk
The type of the file system is NTFS.
Volume label is 2TB.

WARNING!  /F parameter not specified.
Running CHKDSK in read-only mode.

Stage 1: Examining basic file system structure ...
Attribute list entry with type code 30 in file 182A is corrupt.
Attribute list entry with type code 80 in file 182A is corrupt.
Deleted corrupt attribute list entry
with type code 80 in file 182A.
Attribute record (80, "") from file record segment 182A
is corrupt.
Attribute record (80, "") from file record segment 1832
is corrupt.
Attribute record (80, "") from file record segment 183E
is corrupt.
Attribute record (80, "") from file record segment 184B
is corrupt.
Attribute record (80, "") from file record segment 184C
is corrupt.
Attribute record (80, "") from file record segment 44CD
is corrupt.
Attribute record (80, "") from file record segment 44CE
is corrupt.
Attribute record (80, "") from file record segment 44CF
is corrupt.
Attribute record (80, "") from file record segment 44D0
is corrupt.
  92672 file records processed.
File verification completed.
 Phase duration (File record verification): 2.38 seconds.
File record segment 1832 is an orphan.
File record segment 183E is an orphan.
File record segment 184B is an orphan.
File record segment 184C is an orphan.
File record segment 44CD is an orphan.
File record segment 44CE is an orphan.
File record segment 44CF is an orphan.
File record segment 44D0 is an orphan.
  281 large file records processed.
 Phase duration (Orphan file record recovery): 0.00 milliseconds.

Errors found.  CHKDSK cannot continue in read-only mode.
```

Comment: If you can access it in Windows 10 and assuming the file system is NTFS then run chkdsk in Windows before anything else and, of course, make sure Fast Startup is disabled and the Windows 10 system properly shutdown before testing again.

Comment: @ChanganAuto, just edited my post.

Comment: You need to error correct the drive, the output is telling exactly that and that is totally expected. How to use chkdsk parameters to fix it is a Windows question and I won't go into details about it. As a courtesy I can recommend the GUI error correction tool accessible by right-clicking the drive (actually partition) > Properties.

Comment: This is exactly why you NEED Windows if you use NTFS as that Microsoft proprietary file system can only be corrected in Windows with Windows tools. In a nutshell, your question has nothing to do with Ubuntu.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I'll check it myself.